# Wrapping text within a multirow cell

Tags: tables

I've managed to create a table with multirow and multicolumn with fixed widths in the columns. However, I cannot change the width of the column that contains 'Condition'. Ideally I want the text within the column to wrap. Does someone know how I can get the text to wrap and be a set width? Right now I gave it the default '*'. Thank you!

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Condition} &

    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Metrics} \\
    \cline{2-7}

    & \multicolumn{2}{|C{3cm}|}{Length ($\mu$m)}
    & \multicolumn{2}{|C{3cm}|}{Width ($\mu$m)}
    & \multicolumn{2}{|C{3cm}|}{Area ($\mu$m\textsuperscript{2})} \\

    \cline{2-7}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{Mean}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{SD}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{Mean}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{SD}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{Mean}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{SD}  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.StackExchange.  Your description is great... however a complete code with the `\documentclass` and `\usepackage`s relevant to your example might help contributors even more precisely.

Comment: Apart from your question, you might be interested in the `siunitx` package. It could be useful if you are going to fill your table with numbers as the package introduces a new `S` column that allows you to align numbers with respect to their decimal separator. Apart from that you might also want to have a look at the `booktabs` package.

Comment: Do you just want the word 'Condition' to get hyphenated if it shows up in the first column, or should all long words in the first column get hyphenated (if needed, of course)? Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using fixed column widths and the `m` column type, I would load the `tabularx` package and use its `tabularx` environment. This approach makes sure that the table will fit inside the width of the text block. In addition, the `X` column type (and derived column types, such as `C` and `L` in the example below) allow automatic line-wrapping.

I would also omit all vertical bars (they're not needed! really!) and use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline` and `\cline`. Oh, and do look into the `siunitx` package and, in particular, this package's `\si` macro that simplifies the consistent writing of scientific units)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}L@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % optional (default is 6pt)

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{6}{C} @{}}
\toprule
\mytab{Condition} & \multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{Metrics} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-7}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Length (\si{\micro\meter})}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Width (\si{\micro\meter})}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Area (\si{\micro\meter\squared})} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} 
& Mean & SD & Mean & SD & Mean & SD  \\
\midrule
Whatever & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
$\cdots$ \\
Whatever \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You now have a `{=}` argument for \multirows inserted in fixed width columns.

Unrelated: the symbol for `micro`  in units uses an *upright* mu, not the default italic mu from maths fonts. It's better to use `siunits`x` to have a correct typing of units.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}


\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{C{1cm}|}}
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{=}{Condi\-tion} &
    \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Metrics} \\
    \cline{2-7}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Length (\si{\um})}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Width (\si{\um})}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Area (\si{\um\squared})} \\
    \cline{2-7}
    & Mean
    & SD
    & Mean
    & SD
    & Mean
    & SD \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: You're right. Actually, I didn't check details of the original code, and mainly focused on \multirow. I'll fix that in a moment. Thank you for pointing the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Without much expertise in `multirow` I changes the `*` to `0.6cm` in the second parameter of `\multirow{3}{0.6cm}{Con\-di\-tion}` and added possible hyphenations to "Condition".  This produced the following table, which might be close to what you want:

[image]

Here's the complete code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

    \hline
    \multirow{3}{0.6cm}{Con\-di\-tion} &

    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Metrics} \\
    \cline{2-7}

    & \multicolumn{2}{|C{3cm}|}{Length ($\mu$m)}
    & \multicolumn{2}{|C{3cm}|}{Width ($\mu$m)}
    & \multicolumn{2}{|C{3cm}|}{Area ($\mu$m\textsuperscript{2})} \\

    \cline{2-7}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{Mean}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{SD}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{Mean}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{SD}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{Mean}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{SD}  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```